# How to capture only non-selected value from the dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to capture the non selected values from the drop down.
Please help me

Comment: Please share your code trials.

Comment: I dont know how to do it. thats why i am asking

Comment: share your html code for the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("")));
List<WebElement> alloption = sel.getOptions();
for (WebElement webElement : alloption) {
    boolean checkele=webElement.isSelected();
    if(checkele==false) {
        System.out.println("non-selected elements : "+webElement.getText());
    }
}
```